# epoll returning with 0 events

Tags: c, linux

I have two file descriptors, one read file descriptor on pipe and another socket connection descriptor. Neither of them is non blocking. Both of them are added to epoll context with single EPOLLIN event. Lastly, i call epoll_wait with timeout = -1. Below is the sample code. I have 
two questions :-

1. Do pipe and connection descriptors need to be non blocking. This is not edge triggered. If yes, is it good practice or mandatory and if mandatory, why ?
2. I am setting timeout to -1, yet epoll_wait returns immediately with the return value 0. Why is that happening? with timeout of -1, epoll_wait should only return if there is an event.

   ```
   int total_fd_ready = -1;
   struct epoll_event pipe_event, connection_event, total_events[64];

   pipe_event.data.fd = pipe_fd[0];
   piple_event.events = EPOLLIN;
   connection_event.data.fd = conn_fd;
   connection_event.events = EPOLLIN;

   total_fd_ready = Epoll_wait(epoll_fd, total_events, 64, -1);
    printf("%d\n", total_fd_ready);
   ```

   Epoll_wait is defined as

   ```
   int Epoll_wait(int e_fd, struct epoll_event *events, int max_events, int timeout)
   {
   #ifdef DBG
           printf("Epoll_wait called on epoll_fd: %d with max_events: %d and timeout: %d\n", e_fd, max_events, timeout);
   #endif

   int result = -1;
   if(result = (epoll_wait(e_fd, events, max_events, timeout)) < 0)
           if(errno != EINTR)
                   err_sys("epoll_wait error with epoll fd: %d and timeout : %d\n", e_fd, timeout);
           #ifdef DBG
           else
                   printf("epoll_wait was interrupted\n");
           #endif
   return result;
   }
   ```

UPDATE:
found the issue, though i cannot explain why result is set to 0. i needed bracers in the following if statement

```
 if((result = (epoll_wait(e_fd, events, max_events, timeout))) < 0)
```

Comment: How do you declare and initialize `total_events`?

Comment: updated the code with it

Comment: And if have compiled with warnings enabled, e.g. with `gcc -Wall`, the compiler would have warned you appropriately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that the comparison operator `<` has higher precedence than assignment, which means that `result`  gets assigned the result of the expression `(epoll_wait(e_fd, events, max_events, timeout)) < 0`.

Comment: Ah , that makes sense, thank you!! Would you know if i need to make my file descriptors non blocking for epoll to work? i dont understand why for edge triggered scenarios, file descriptors should be made non blocking

Comment: Bacause you don't know if your next call to `read(2)` is going to block, totally defeeting the multiplexing nature of `epoll(7)`.

Comment: why would call to read block if epoll returned the socket descriptor with EPOLLIN event? Typically, i register the socket fd for read event and then when epoll_wait returns, i check if socket fd is part of the "events" and if it is, then it should not block. Even with 0 timeout, one would check if the returned "events" contained the socket to be read.

Comment: Becase in edge-triggered setup you are supposed to read until you get `EAGAIN`, and that's not possible with blocking descriptor.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov where is this mandatory? EAGAIN has to do with non blocking aspect of the read. Infact, i have working example with blocking read and edge triggered. I know the size of the data which i am supposed to read, say 1KB. if read returns partial data, i simply read the partial data and wait for epoll_wait to make it readable again.

Comment: It's not mandatory. You can shoot yourself in the foot as much as you want to.